# Rails find by username issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new rails developer trying to get urls like:

```
www.twitter.com/theusername
```

Here's my route:

```
match "/:username" => "posts#index"
```

this works and routes my localhost:3000/theusername to localhost:3000/posts/

then I use:

```
def index
  @user = User.find_by_username params[:username]
  @search = Post.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:user, @user.id)
    paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 20)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this brings up the error:

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 8 -- if you really wanted
>   the id of nil, use object_id

Also, the web server brings up this (in case it helps):

```
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"username"=>"test"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = 'test' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

RuntimeError (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 8 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:10:in `block in index'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Comment: what's the return value for User.find_by_username params[:username] ?

Comment: did you make sure that params[:username] is actually a username string?

Comment: User.find_by_username params[:username] is returning a nil value (not finding a user). What /:username are you trying and is that a value in the database (exactly - case, spacing, etc.)?

Comment: @rogerdpack, `#<User:0x00000104b45528>`

Comment: @BigLoppy, and huy. I just double checked and I have a user in the database with username = test, and I'm going to localhost:3000/test

Comment: what's the value of @user.id ?

Comment: According to your SQL statements, 2 users are loaded, the first with `"id" = 2` and the second with `"username" = 'test'`

Comment: @Stefan, Why would there be two SQL statements? Does find_by_username generate two sql queries?

Comment: just ask, @the_ are you using sunspot and will_paginate gem?

Comment: @anonymousxxx yes I'm using both

Comment: I am wondering if this has something to do with the Posts rather than the user or url...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ever wondered why it is that inside your `Post.search` block you are able to call methods such as `fulltext` even though there is no such method on your controller ?

It's because inside that block `self` has been changed (by `instance_eval`). This is sometimes convenient, particularly when building DSLs such as sunspot's since the DSL methods are then callable without a receiver

However this means that within that block `@user` refers to an instance variable of the sunspot object (which doesn't have one) and so it is nil. It looks like sunspot has some clever code to proxy methods to the original calling method (that's why calling `params`) works, but that sort of trick doesn't work with instance variables.

The quick way around this is to do

```
@search = Post.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:search]
    query.with(:user, @user.id)
end
```

This makes the block a bog standard one with no changing of `self`, at the price of a little verbosity.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks so much for the explanation as well!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `to_param` method in your User model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param 
    username
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried this and still didn't work? Same error as above.

Comment: the problem is you are trying to map index action which dont take any parameter like :username, you have to map url like this : "/:username/posts" for index.

Comment: do you mean change to this: match "/:username/posts" => "posts#index"? I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: the way you are trying to map url is going against rails convention.In rails you have to do www.twitter.com/2/posts, or by using to_param you can do www.twitter.com/username/posts. but mapping in ur way is possible, but it will need more digging into your code, like model relationship etc..

Answer (score 0):

That error you're getting is called a **whiny nil**. It's raised when you try to call the `id` method on `nil`.

It's probably related to your `@user.id`. If `@user` is nil, calling `@user.id` will throw up a whiny nil error.

That's only in Rails 3, though. In Rails 4, whiny nils have been replaced by the regular  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: When I print out `@user.id` it says `2` though?

Comment: I can tell you you're getting a whiny nil. Debugging your app is another matter.